# how to append suffix after makefile's automatic variable?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
OBJS := a.o b.o c.o

rule : $(OBJS)
  @echo $^
  @echo $^.bc // @echo a.o.bc b.o.bc c.o.bc -> what I want to do
```

I want to add suffix after automatic variable `$^`

However, even though I use `$^.bc`, it shows

```
a.o b.o c.o.bc
```

not,

```
a.o.bc b.o.bc c.o.bc
```

Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: with GNU make you can use the [`addsuffix` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions): `$(addsuffix .bc,$^)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Problem

The automatic variable [`$^`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) is in your case a space-separated list of elements since it expands to `a.o b.o c.o`.
Therefore, `echo $^.bc` will result in `a.o b.o c.o.bc` instead of `a.o.bc b.o.bc c.o.bc`, because the suffix `.bc` is only appended to the last element of the list, i.e., `c.o`.

If you want to obtain `a.o.bc b.o.bc c.o.bc`, then what you want is to add the suffix `.bc` to *every single element of that space-separated list*, not just the last one.

---

#### Solution

GNU Make's [`addsuffix`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) builtin function does work on lists:

```
OBJS := a.o b.o c.o

rule: $(OBJS)
    @echo $^
    @echo $(addsuffix .bc,$^)
```

Running `make` on the makefile above:

```
$ make
a.o b.o c.o
a.o.bc b.o.bc c.o.bc
```

produces the output you are looking for.

Comment: addsuffix resolves my issue, which gives me a.o.bc b.o.bc c.o.bc Thks